# Change font in Tablayout view

Tags: android, view, fonts

I want to change font family on my tabs, depends on which tab is selected. I want set fon bold for selected tabs and light font for unselected
I have this fonts in my package /font

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the font family for selected/unselected tab only programmatically. You can listen which Tab is selected and unselected with **TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener** and on **onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)** callback you can change the Typeface for the selected Tab and on **onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)** callback you can change the Typeface for the unselected Tab (the Previous Selected Tab).

This can be achieve in code like below:

```
tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

//initial selected Tab
TabLayout.Tab selectedTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
setTabTypeface(selectedTab, ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.roboto_mono));

//add OnTabSelectedListener
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
   @Override
   public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
      setTabTypeface(tab, ResourcesCompat.getFont(tab.view.getContext(), R.font.roboto_mono));
   }

   @Override
   public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
      setTabTypeface(tab, ResourcesCompat.getFont(tab.view.getContext(), R.font.extra_light_italic));
  }

  @Override
  public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
  }
});
```

with the helper function **setTabTypeface(TabLayout.Tab tab, Typeface typeface)** to change the typeface for the Tab like below:

```
private void setTabTypeface(TabLayout.Tab tab, Typeface typeface){

        for(int i=0; i<tab.view.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View tabViewChild = tab.view.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView)
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }
```

Of Course you have to set for all Tabs the initial/default state (the unselected font family) which can be set in xml using the  **app:tabTextAppearance** attribute of TabLayout like in the below example:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" >

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tab 1" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tab 2" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tab 3" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

where **@style/MyCustomTextAppearance** is your custom initial TextAppearance Style for all Tabs like below:

```
<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/extra_light_italic</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/extra_light_italic</item>
</style>
```

To change also the Text Color for the selected/unselected Tab you can use the xml attributes **app:tabSelectedTextColor** and **app:tabTextColor** of your TabLayout.

Result of the above example will be like below. I have set Roboto Mono typeface for the selected Tab and an Extra Light Italic typeface for the unselected tab retrieved from Font folder.
[image: tablayout]

Answer (score 0):

```
tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
//to update color
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.RED);
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.RED,Color.GREEN);
            
        //once you set the view pager to tablayout then add below loop
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);       
        
            for (int a = 0; a < tabLayout.getTabCount(); a++){
                     TabLayout.Tab selectedTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(a);
                     setTabTypeface(selectedTab, ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.roboto_bold));           
                }
       //add this Function to your class     
                private void setTabTypeface(TabLayout.Tab tab, Typeface typeface){    
                        for(int i=0; i<tab.view.getChildCount(); i++){
                            View tabViewChild = tab.view.getChildAt(i);
                            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView)
                                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(typeface);
                        }
                    }
```